# if-else code for total price won't compile

Tags: c, if-statement

what is wrong with this im to make c code for total price with one of three ram options.et ramchoices=1or2or3 /*this is where I know my problem lies but don't know how to fix it.  the compiler needs a one to one relationship. how do I break this up and still show that ramchoice depends on what I pick and those choices affect price.*/

```
int main(void) {
/*declare variables*/
float baseprice;
float total;
float ramchoice;
baseprice=1029.48;

/*ramchoice can be 1 or 2 or 3*/

ramchoice=1||ramchoice=2||ramchoice=3;
total=baseprice+ramchoice;

/*initiate variable*/

scanf("%f",&ramchoice);
if("%f" (ramchoice==1))
{
    total=baseprice+179.99;
}
else if("%f" ramchoice==2)
{
    total=baseprice+94.99;
}
else if("%f" ramchoice==3)
{
    total=baseprice+69.99;
}

printf("total is %f",total);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Add the programming language as a tag please.

Comment: I'm not shure this works ramchoice=1||ramchoice=2||ramchoice=3; What do you mean with this?

Comment: What is `"%f"` doing in the `if` statements? That's only used in `printf` and `scanf`.

Comment: What do you expect `("%f" ramchoice==3)` to evaluate to ?

Comment: "Won't compile" means your compiler says "I won't compile this", or does it show errors, warnings, and more of that kind, annotated with line numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are several lines that are unlike any C code I've ever seen before.
Are you completely making up your own syntax and meaning?
Have you read any instructions/tutorials on C?

```
ramchoice=1||ramchoice=2||ramchoice=3;
```

Whatever you think this line does, it sets variable `ramchoice` to have value `1`, then it stops.

---

```
if("%f" (ramchoice==1))
```

`if` does NOT take a string like `"%f"`.   `if` expects a boolean expression.
You're close to a boolean with `ramchoice==1`, but the `"%f"` at the start is so very wrong.

---

**Seriously, you cannot make up rules to a language and pray that it works.**

Here is my re-write that pretty much fixes your issues:

```
int main(void)
{
    /*declare variables*/
    float baseprice = 1029.48;
    float total;
    int   ramchoice;

    printf("Please enter a ram selection: 1, 2, or 3\n");
    scanf("%d",&ramchoice);
    switch(ramchoice)
    {
        case 1:   total=baseprice+179.99; break;
        case 2:   total=baseprice+94.99;  break;
        case 3:   total=baseprice+69.99;  break;
        default:  printf("That was not a valid choice\n");
    }

    printf("total is %f",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's somethings in your code that make no sence (are not correct in C):

- ramchoice=1||ramchoice=2||ramchoice=3; total=baseprice+ramchoice;
- "%f" (ramchoice==1)

The first I don't understand why you are using it.
The second one gives me the idea that your not understanding how scanf works.

Also, you are declaring ramchoice as a float, but you are comparing it to another value (1, 2 or 3). Due to the representation of float values, this may not work. I mean, if you have float x = 1; and then do x == 1, it may return false. To fix this you can just change it to an int (in this case, in others you can use an error margin).
Here's a fix of your code:

```
int main(void) {
/*declare variables*/
float baseprice;
float total;
int ramchoice; 
baseprice=1029.48;

/*initiate variable*/

scanf("%i",&ramchoice);
if(ramchoice==1)
{
    total=baseprice+179.99;
}
else if(ramchoice==2)
{
    total=baseprice+94.99;
}
else if(ramchoice==3)
{
    total=baseprice+69.99;
}

printf("total is %f",total);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of the "%f" in the if statements
2. Comment those 2 lines:

> ```
> ramchoice=1||ramchoice=2||ramchoice=3;
> total=baseprice+ramchoice;
> ```

and code should compile.